# How to scan big map with small scanner into one file

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, scanner

I need to scan big map with scanner that supports max A4 size. I san scan map in several A4 pieces. But then I need to combine these pieces into one file. How to stitch these images?

Comment: Requests for product recommendations are off-topic. You may want to research how to stitch images?

Comment: Maybe they mean how to stitch them using PhotoShop?

Comment: Simply create a blank canvas of the combined size, then paste and move each of the pieces into the appropriate places on the canvas, a layer at a time. If you allow enough overlap, you may be able to use a panorama creation program, rotating if necessary for vertical stitching.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this on a regular basis.

If you have Photoshop, you can use Photomerge (File>Automate>Photomerge) as long as there is sufficient overlap for the images.

Otherwise, you can use any advanced image software that has layers (e.g. GIMP), import each scan as a separate layer, set those layers to 50% alpha, match up the edges and then flatten the image.